# Problem: Find the numbers from range (1,1000) where the iterative sum of squares of the digits of the numbers are 1

Tags: python-3.x

```py
for value in range(0,1000):
   def digisum(value):
       x= sum(int(c) ** 2 for c in str(value))
   def iteration(value):
       if x in [0,1]:
           print (value)
       else:
           iteration(digisum(x))
```

I am getting an error as 'maximum recursive density exceeded'

Comment: 1,10,100,1000 is the answer... You sure about the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume by "iterative sum of squares of digits", you mean 'find the sum of the squares of the digits, and keep going until you reach a one-digit number'. If you do, this code should work for you:

```
def digit_sum(x):
    while x > 9:
        x = sum([int(i)**2 for i in str(x)])
    return x

for n in range(1, 1001):
    if digit_sum(n) == 1:
        print(n)
```

Output:

```
1
10
13
19
23
28
31
32
44
49
68
70
79
82
86
91
94
97
100
103
109
129
130
133
139
167
176
188
190
192
193
203
208
219
226
230
236
239
262
263
280
291
293
301
302
310
313
319
320
326
329
331
338
356
362
365
367
368
376
379
383
386
391
392
397
404
409
440
446
464
469
478
487
490
496
536
556
563
565
566
608
617
622
623
632
635
637
638
644
649
653
655
656
665
671
673
680
683
694
700
709
716
736
739
748
761
763
784
790
793
802
806
818
820
833
836
847
860
863
874
881
888
899
901
904
907
910
912
913
921
923
931
932
937
940
946
964
970
973
989
998
1000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out my mistake. I should declare the loop outside the function. Your code is absolutely right. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
for value in range(1+1,1000):
    if sum(int(c)**2 for c in str(value)) == 1:
        print(value)
```

As the range is exclusive, 1 and 1000 are left out. The output and correct answer is 10 and 100.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to define a function inside a for loop (doing it 1000 times).
Inside the iteration function you ask if x is in [0, 1] but x is not defined inside that function. What do you mean by iterative sum? Is this just summing all squares of digits?

Adapting your code you could do something like this

```
def digitsumsquarediterative(value):
    res = sum(int(c) ** 2 for c in str(value))
    return res if res < 10 else digitsumsquarediterative(res)


for i in range(1, 2):
    if digitsumsquarediterative(i) == 1:
        print(i)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in your code you have calculated the sum of squares of digits just ones. whereas, we need to calculate it till it hits a result 1 iteratively.   For example: 32

    3^2 + 2^2 = 13
    1^2 + 3^2 = 10
    1^2 + 0^2 = 1

Comment: @Soumonos did not understood that part :) Just editted the answer to take that into consideration